# adding phase and amplitude noise in ideal signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, communication, digital

I want to add phase and amplitude noise in frequency modulated siganl. I need to add diffrent diffrent levels of the phase noise in the signal and need to see how the output changes.

equation for the frequency modulated signl is s = A * cos(2*pi*fc.*t + 2*pi*bw*int_x + init_phase). Here what shoud i take as init_phase(phase noise) = ? and A = ?.

```
function [st] = freqmod(fc,fs, bw, x, t,init_phase)
%VCO_FUNCTION Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
if nargin < 6
    init_phase = 0;
end

if (fs < 2*fc)  
    disp('Error: fs must at least 2*fc');
    return;
end

int_x = cumsum(x)/fs;
st = cos(2*pi*fc.*t + 2*pi *bw*int_x + init_phase);   % Frequency modulation 

end
```

Comment: What is `int_x`?  It is undefined in your function.  Also, an explanation of the parameters would be nice.  For example, what does `bw` represent? Shouldn't that be `fs`? `fc` would be the frequency of the carrier wave, which of course makes sense, but it's unclear as to what your modulating signal is.  Would that be the cosine wave? Please double check your code for correctness, then edit it accordingly.  It's our job to help you fix problems, not try and interpret what you have written ultimately leading to more work on our part.

Comment: Hey rayryeng. Thanks for your reply. I am first generating sawtooth wave which is x and after that i am giving it to the vco function in order to get the frequency modulated signal. Here, int_x is integration of the signal generator ouput x. I am using bandwidth here since my signal x is swept from 70KHz untill 110KHz, therefore, i can not take only one single frequency fc in the formula.

Comment: why don't you want to add some Gaussian noise? For example    st = (1+n_A*rand)*cos(2*pi*fc.*t + 2*pi *bw*int_x + n_f*rand(size(t)));   % Frequency modulation    where n_A and n_f are variances for your Amplitude and frequency respectively. Sorry for bad editing, didn't learn it yet.